# Regex Combination for accepting only word or only letters for laravel validation

Tags: regex, laravel

Im having difficulty constructing a regex validation for laravel that accepts only characters or only digits. It goes something like this:

- Hello <- ok
- 123 <- ok
- hello123 <-not ok

my regex right now is something like this: [A-Za-z]|[0-9].

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/ldWNu2/1)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Take a look at this Regex:**

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$|^[0-9]+$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ldWNu2/2)

You were close, but you must add the start of line `^` and end of line `$` tags, as well as the `+` to match at least 1 to unlimited times.

**Explanation:**

```
^            # start of line
[a-zA-Z]+    # match a-zA-Z recursively
$            # end of line
|            # OR
^            # start of line
[0-9]+       # match [0-9] recursively
$            # end of line
```

**Bonus:**

If you have a block text and you want to extract matches that are either only letters or only digits, instead of start and end characters you can use word boundaries:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]+\b|\b[0-9]+\b
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ldWNu2/4)

Comment: and especially add the + signs!

Comment: Many thanks! Never occured to me that you could use + since most of the examples i saw is something like this: ^[A-Z]*$|^[0-9]*$ and it didn't work on the number part of the regex.